# Trouble upgrading to new com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.0 library

Tags: android

I have an an android app that is working correctly on 24.0.0 -- below are my gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:24.0.0'
    compile files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
}
```

But I downloaded the most recent SDK, and am interested in upgrading to 24.2.0.  Since I need the support libraries, I added com.android.support:support-v4 to the dependencies as follows:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:24.2.0'
    compile files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
}
```

This causes the following exception:

```
   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 
     'android.graphics.drawable.Drawable[] android.widget.TextView.getCompoundDrawables()' 
     on a null object reference
     at android.support.v4.widget.TextViewCompat.getCompoundDrawablesRelative(TextViewCompat.java:285)
```

Did I miss something in the documentation that I should do outside of including support-v4 when upgrading?  This is my reference:
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html#v4

> Note: Prior to Support Library revision 24.2.0, there was a single v4 support library. That library was divided into multiple modules to improve efficiency. For backwards compatibility, if you list support-v4 in your Gradle script, your APK will include all of the v4 modules.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you inspect a dependency tree, `'com.android.support:design'` includes `appcompat-v7`, which includes `support-v4`, so you shouldn't even need to add support-v4 as a line

Comment: I get the same result when omitting support-v4

Comment: I wasn't saying it would fix the problem, I was simply pointing out that adding the line wasn't necessary.

Comment: And, yes, please provide the full Gradle file so we may try to reproduce the problem

Comment: I have the same issue, I am using a Spinner inside TextInputLayout instead, the TextInputLayout is trying to access to get the compounddrawables of the edittext which throws a nullPointerException, What I did was downgrade to 24.1.1 until this issue is fixed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I get the exact same exception after upgrading to support library revision 24.2.0 and build tools 24.0.2 when trying to inflate a layout that includes a TextInputLayout that does NOT have an EditText inside of it.

If I comment out the TextInputLayout without the EditText inside it, the exception goes away.  If this is not possible, I would recommend rolling back to the previous version of the support library until this is resolved.

Comment: Issue has been reported to the Android team.  https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=221206

Comment: This is exactly it -- the designer added some empty TextInputLayouts to the xml, and once I removed them everything started working as planned.  Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: In the issue I reported Google says this is fixed in 24.2.1.

Answer (score 0):

update your Android Sdk Build-tools to

```
24.0.2
```

and add them as buildtools in module app build.gradle

Try to clean & rebuild your project 
it helps to clear previous applied dependencies from cache.

**update**

Try to run this app in Api24  with 7.0 emulator since your target sdk is 24
may be it will help you
but as your min sdk is 21 so this also works on that emulators too.

also follow this 
Android Studio->  File -> Invalidate cache and Restart android studio
Invalidate Restart

Comment: Unfortunately I am using build tools 24.0.2:
        compileSdkVersion 24
        buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

Comment: Had to post as an answer because of the character limit.

Comment: <pre>
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    }
</pre>

Comment: can you please provide the full code in question please

Comment: I commented everything else out but that -- and it crashes.  I can spin up a new emulator and give it a shot, but ultimately this needs to run on Android 5.0

Comment: and the ultimate solution is to simply follow my answer and create a new project in android studio and check whether it cause the same error or not

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking that -- if I must upgrade, I can create a new project and import all of the modules from the previous one.  I was just hoping to figure out why this error was happening outside of doing all of that extra work.

Comment: I have not said to copy all your stuff to new project ,I just said to check a new project if it runs clearly means there is no problem in android studio and also in sdk , emulator

Comment: another thing is ,when we make a new project Android Studio automatically applied the latest dependdncies , so  you can copy the gradle code from it to your app

Answer (score 0):

It can be that you are wrapping something other than a

```
android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
```

with a

```
android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently hit this problem and found the issue to be the following in the layout file

```
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp">

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText>
```

This was from the default google login example.

Removing this fixed the nullpointer error.